# uninitialized constant controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Im doing clean project and after creating the show method to get a specific product i get the error: `uninitialized constant controller rails`

This is the error in console:

> Started GET "/products/2" for ::1 at 2019-10-12 17:04:49 -0400
>     (0.1ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
>   Processing by ProductsController#show as HTML
>    Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | >Allocations: 2988)
>   NameError (uninitialized constant ProductsController::Products):
>
> app/controllers/products_controller.rb:22:in `show'

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price))
    if @product.save
      redirect_to @product
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def product_params
    params.requires(:product).permit(:name, :price)
  end
end
```

I expect the output of my product related to my ID.

Comment: What's the whols stacktrace error? What's in the line 22?

Comment: Line 22:         `@product = Product.find(params[:id])`

Comment: I don't see any reference to Products. Did you try stoping and/or restarting spring (spring stop)?

Comment: Solved! `spring stop` and `spring start`

Comment: Use `product_params` in new method `@product = Product.new(product_params)`  (not related to the problem)